# Covariance matrix of autoregressive process

Tags: time-series, covariance, autoregressive

I am learning about autoregressive processes and there is something that I find unclear about the structure of their covariance matrix. Some sources (e.g. Box and Jenkins, 2016) describe the *autocovariance matrix* of a stationary process $(z_1,z_2,...,z_n)$ as:

\begin{equation}
\Gamma_n=\begin{bmatrix}
\gamma_0&\gamma_1&\gamma_2&\cdots&\gamma_{n-1}\\
\gamma_1&\gamma_0&\gamma_1&\cdots&\gamma_{n-2}\\
\gamma_2&\gamma_1&\gamma_0&\cdots&\gamma_{n-3}\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\cdots&\vdots\\
\gamma_{n-1}&\gamma_{n-2}&\gamma_{n-3}&\cdots&\gamma_0
\end{bmatrix}=\sigma^2_z\begin{bmatrix}
1&\rho_1&\rho_2&\cdots&\rho_{n-1}\\
\rho_1&1&\rho_1&\cdots&\rho_{n-2}\\
\rho_2&\rho_1&1&\cdots&\rho_{n-3}\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\cdots&\vdots\\
\rho_{n-1}&\rho_{n-2}&\rho_{n-3}&\cdots&1
\end{bmatrix}=\sigma^2_z\mathbf{P}_n
\end{equation}
where both the covariance and correlation matrices are constant along the diagonals. In order to estimate the autocovariance function for $\gamma_k$ we can use:
\begin{equation}
c_k=\hat\gamma_k=\frac{1}{N}\sum^{N-k}_{t=1}(z_t-\bar{z})(z_{t+k}-\bar{z})\qquad k=0,1,2,...,K
\end{equation}
where $\bar{z}$ is the sample mean of the series. The kth lag autocorrelation is then $\hat\rho_k=\frac{c_k}{c_0}$. This should also hold for autoregressive processes of the type:
\begin{equation}
z_t=\theta_1z_{t-1}+\theta_2z_{t-2}+...+\theta_pz_{t-p}+\epsilon_t
\end{equation}
as long as they are stationary.

However, sources that specifically treat autoregressive processes give a specific form for the covariance of the autoregressive process defined in terms of the regression parameters ($\theta_k$), (e.g. van der Leeuw, 1992):

\begin{equation}
V=[P^TP-QQ^T]^{-1}
\end{equation}
where P is a TxT matrix taking the form
\begin{equation}
P=\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&0\\
\theta_1&1&0&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&0\\
\theta_2&\theta_1&1&0&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&0\\
\vdots&\theta_2&\theta_1&1&0&\ddots&\ddots&0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots\\
\theta_p&\theta_{p-1}&\ddots&\theta_2&\theta_1&1&\cdots&0\\
\vdots&\theta_p&\theta_{p-1}&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&1&0\\
0&0&\theta_p&\theta_{p-1}&\ddots&\ddots&\cdots&1
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
while Q is a (T-p)x(T-p) matrix taking the form:
\begin{equation}
Q=\begin{bmatrix}
\theta_p&\theta_{p-1}&\cdots&\theta_1\\
0&\theta_p&\cdots&\theta_2\\
0&0&\ddots&\vdots\\
0&0&\cdots&\theta_p\\
\vdots&\cdots&\cdots&0\\
0&\cdots&\cdots&0\\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

The matrices are clearly computed differently, but are they related in some way? Can the first be regarded as the sample covariance matrix while the second as the theoretical covariance matrix, or are they describing two different quantities?

**References**

Box, Jenkins (2016). *Time Series Analysis*. Wiley.

van der Leeuw (1992) "The covariance matrix of ARMA-errors in closed form". *Journal of Econometrics*.

Comment: It doesn't address your specific question, but the answers to [this Prais-Winsten GLS question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/246337) might be insightful.

Comment: Hi Lester: The first matrix you have written is probably the covariance for an AR(1). ( it's still an n by n matrix because there's covariance between an observation at $t$ and the observation at $t+n$ ). The covariance matrix for an ar(p) is much more algebraically involved so that's probably what the second one is. The two are not comparable so the sentence where you say "this should hold" is not true. I hope this helps.